# Loop through an object and push key and value into an array

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to pass in an object with some data inside, I then want to push the results in that object into an array, but still keep the key and value names.

The data passed in:

```
App.config({
    dependencies: : {
        'html5shiv' : 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js',
        'respondjs' : 'http://respondjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/respond.js'
    }
});
```

My array and logic (indicated where I'm stuck!):

```
var deps = [];
App.config = function (obj) {
    var dep = obj.dependencies;
    for (var key in dep) {
        if (dep.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            deps.push( /* stuck here */ );
        }
    }
    console.log(deps);
};
```

What I want *'deps'* to end up with is:

```
[{
    'html5shiv': 'http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'
},{
    'respondjs': 'http://respondjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/respond.js'
}];
```

Can anyone advise on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var key in dep) {
        if (dep.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            deps.push( dep[key].html5shiv);
            deps.push( dep[key].respondjs);
        }
    }
```

**Updates:**

```
for (var key in dep) {
     if (dep.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          deps.push({key: dep[key]}); //Dynamic
      }
 }
```

Comment: That only pushes the key, I need to actually push an object, I thought you could do it like .push({key:obj}) but its not working.

Comment: Will give you that, needed to be dynamic not hard coded but it helped :)

Comment: @Halcyon21 `deps.push({key: dep[key]})` is this what you got working.  Can you share it?

Comment: Sure: if (dep.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var newObj = {};
                newObj[key] = dep[key];
                deps.push(newObj);
            }

Comment: @Halcyon21 Oh, by creating a temp obj and then pushing it to array.  pretty nice.  Is it similar to `deps.push({key: dep[key]})`?

Comment: Yeah, worked real nice. Well, it's exactly the same but allows the 'key' to be dynamic, actually adding the word 'key' inside the .push() prevents it from being dynamic, or it actually prints out: {key: 'ajax.googleapis.com/bla.js'} :)!

Comment: @Halcyon21 Oh, can't guess the reason.  Anyway thanks for sharing and had a really nice chat :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
deps.push(dep[key]);
```